# Rails 3 - How to embed inline Images that are hosted on S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip, actionmailer

in my Rails 3 app, I send out emails that include user profile pictures. Problem is GMAIL always shows the "Click to allow Images to Display" type of warning.

How can I embed the images inside the email so there are no external URL calls to get the images? Also, the images are on S3 thanks to paperclip and not stored locally.

Thanks

Comment: For anyone who missed it, gmail doesn't require the user to "click to allow images" anymore.  They automatically scan images for evil and display them if they pass. http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2013/12/images-now-showing.html

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't force an email client to accept any kind of picture, whether it's embedded or an external URL.  What you can do is include your pictures as attachments to the email instead of simply embedding them. That said, different email clients handle attachments in different ways, but GMAIL for example will scan the attachments and then display them below the message. If you want to have your images actually embeded with the text you'll have to settle for the 'Click to allow Images to Display', since it's there for security reasons and is out of your control.

Comment: How does AirBnB do it then?